# Removing \n from a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, list

Using this code...

```
def read_restaurants(file):
    file = open('restaurants_small.txt', 'r')
    contents_list = file.readlines()

    for line in contents_list:
      line.strip('\n')

    print (contents_list)
    file.close()
```

read_restaurants('restaurants_small.txt')

I get this result...

['Georgie Porgie\n', '87%\n', '$$$\n', 'Canadian,Pub Food\n', '\n', 'Queen St. Cafe\n', '82%\n', '$\n', 'Malaysian,Thai\n', '\n', 'Dumplings R Us\n', '71%\n', '$\n', 'Chinese\n', '\n', 'Mexican Grill\n', '85%\n', '$$\n', 'Mexican\n', '\n', 'Deep Fried Everything\n', '52%\n', '$\n', 'Pub Food\n']

I want to strip out the \n...I've read through a lot of answers on here that I thought might help, but nothing seems to work specifically with this!

I guess the for...in process needs to be stored as a new list, and I need to return that...just not sure how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

A bit more of a pythonic (and, to my mind, easier to read) approach:

```
def read_restaurants(filename):
    with open(filename) as fh:
        return [line.rstrip() for line in fh]
```

Also, since no one has quite clarified this: the reason your original approach doesn't work is that `line.strip()` returns a modified version of `line`, but it doesn't *alter* `line`:

```
>>> line = 'hello there\n'
>>> print(repr(line))
'hello there\n'
>>> line.strip()
'hello there'
>>> print(repr(line))
'hello there\n']
```

So whenever you call `stringVar.strip()`, you need to do something with the output - build a list, like above, or store it in a variable, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your regular `for` loop with `list comprehension` and you don't have to pass `'\n'` as an argument since `strip()` method removes leading and trailing white characters by default:

```
contents_list = [line.strip() for line in contents_list]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried to put in \r to get rid of the blank lines, but it didn't work...

Comment: contents_list = [line.strip('\n\r') for line in contents_list]

Comment: @YogeshRiyat but as I've written already, you don't have to pass anything as argument to `line.strip()` to remove blank lines, because it's the default behavior of `strip()` method to remove blank characters. But if you really insist to pass an argument then yes, `\n\r` is correct for Windows.

Comment: So, the code worked for getting rid of \n when it was tagged onto a string, but not for the '\n' elements when they were alone.  I did use this filter code, and it worked.  I saw it on some other post,  but I don't really know how it works!

Comment: new_contents_list = [line.strip() for line in contents_list] 
new_contents_list = list(filter(None, new_contents_list))

Answer (score 0):

You are right: you will need a new list. Also, probably you want to use `rstrip()` instead of `strip()`:

```
def read_restaurants(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    contents_list = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    new_contents_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in contents_list]
    return new_contents_list
```

Then you can do the following:

```
print(read_restaurants('restaurant.list'))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm trying to understand why the argument of the function is restaurant.list...can you explain that piece?  would read_restaurants(file) work?

Comment: @YogeshRiyat Good question but only you can answer it because you wrote it! Unfortunately I just blindly copied first lines until `contents_list = file.readlines()`. That is, my code needs `contents_list` and produces `new_contents_list`.

Comment: @YogeshRiyat I modified the code to make more sense: now `read_restaurants()` takes `file_name` (a string) as an argument; opens that file, and read all lines from that file.